Creation of pluralized tags
With reference to this discussion, tags having common nouns should be in plural form. Certain tags have been created as singular tags, and need to be pluralized:

compiler : 4 questions
linux-package : 1 question
microcontroller : 1 question

Feel free to add any other tags that may need to be pluralized
